# Beginner: Can't run this program eventhough it is the solution

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("args[0] = " + args[0]);
        System.out.println("args[1] = " + args[1]);
        System.out.println("args[2] = " + args[2]); 
    }
}
```

The error message I get is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to your program

Comment: `java -cp . Exercise10 a b c`

Comment: So what's the question here? ArrayIndexOutOfBound? thats an duplicate.

Comment: how  are you executing this? `java` command or any ide? if ide pass program arguments, `java` command follow Elliott Frish comment

Comment: I'm running it through Eclipse. Am I supposed to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

The "args" String array argument to main() is populated by the command-line arguments you give to your program when you run it. Since you presumably haven't given it any, looking up the 0th one is quite reasonably an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

If you are invoking this with java on the command line, try `$ java Exercise10 arg0 arg1 arg2`

If you are invoking it from an IDE, you'll need to figure out how that IDE supports passing command line arguments. For example, in Eclipse, I believe there should be an Arguments tab in the Run dialog.

Answer (score 0):

"Arg" as said in the names equals to Arguments, You haven't passed any Argument to your program hence it raises the error `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`, You can pass Arguments to your program by executing it as a jar in command prompt `java -jar myJar.jar a b c`